# Downloading files from shared dropbox location in c#

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, sharpbox

In my application users will give a url to their shared dropbox folder. When it is given I want to grab the images in that url and download to a folder in my application.
Is this achievable?

I've tried to do this in SharpBox. I've managed to open a connection to dropbox storage through SharpBox and successfully connect to my public folders.

But I couldn't find a method which accepts a shared dropbox url and download files from that url.

Thanks